Fantasy series from pre 2010 - Woman follows a man with magic
Been trying to remember a fantasy book I read over 15 years ago. It was the first in a series and followed (I think) a female protagonist who leaves her home (which I think belonged to some lord) and follows a man who can use magic. They travel through a forest and at the end of the book finally arrive at the city where the man is from.
I remember one scene where the pair are being chased by hunting dogs I think and the man manages to calm them down, explaining to the girl that animals don't want to hurt people and can be reasoned with if you know how.
